# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'feature2'. What’s the reason for this error?

Tags: python

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in a init")

    def feature1(self):
        print("feature 1 is working")
    def feature2(self):
        print("feature 2 is working")

    def sink(self):
        super().feature2()


class b(a):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            print("in b init ")

        def feature3(self):
            print("feature 3 is working")

        def feature4(self):
            print("feature 4 is working")


A=a()
A.sink()
```

I tried defining the sink function within class a

Comment: It’s _not_ defined in any of a’s parents, it’s defined in an itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `super()`, python starts looking for members from above the current class. Since there is no `feature2` above `a`, python reports the error.

You could have just used `self`:

```py
    def sink(self):
        self.feature2()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the `super()` function in the `sink()` method of class `a` is trying to access the `feature2()` method from the superclass of `a`, but no such method exists in the superclass.

The superclass of `a` is `object`, *which is the default superclass for all classes in Python*. The `object` class not have `feature2()` method, so when you call `super().feature2()`, it give an `AttributeError`.

To fix this, change `super().feature2()` to `self.feature2()`

```
class a:
    ...

    def sink(self):
        self.feature2()
    ...
```